# How to store large files in SQL using MVC, JavaScript chunking, and Entity Framework

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, upload, filestream

My overall goal is to store large video files (5 GB) in SQL using my MVC app. The highest I can get the web.config to allow file uploads is 3GB, so I found this solution that uses JavaScript to slice the large file into chunks and send it to the controller using AJAX.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1034347/Upload-large-files-to-MVC-WebAPI-using-partitionin

This works fine to store the file on the file system, but I want it in the database. I am using Entity Framework currently to insert this "FileModel", but I obviously cannot take the same approach because the database insert would just be the first data chunk.

I am at a loss as to what to do. I see FileStream mentioned, saving the file to the file system and keeping the file path in the database, but most of these postings online are a little dated. I am running .Net 4.5 and SQL 2012. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Storing such big files in the DB does not sound like a good idea. Why do you want that?
2. Save the files to /temp location and run another script to move them to the DB and delete the file afterward.
3. You can also modify the MergeFile() to use and return a binary stream of the file that you can use to insert into your DB.